# Trying to do addition of 3 objects of class but i get error in that : TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Demo'

Tags: python

## python version 3.0 and above

```
    class Demo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.data = self.data + other.data
        return self.data

d1 = Demo(200)
d2 = Demo(300)
d3 = Demo(100)
print(d1 + d2 + d3)
```

After run this code i get error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Demo'

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? Do you want `d1 + d2` to be an `int`, or a `Demo` instance?

Comment: `return self.data`… Your `+` operation results in an `int`, so the next operation is trying to add an `int` and a `Demo`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *want* your `__add__` implementation to result in a new `Demo` object with the `data` values added together. You should *not modify* `self` inside `__add__`, that's the wrong semantic. You don't expect `Demo(1) + Demo(2)` to modify `Demo(1)`. For that there's explicitly [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__), which corresponds to `+=`.

So, you want:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(self.data + other.data)
```

`Demo(1) + Demo(2)` now returns a `Demo(3)`.

The specific reason your code was failing is that your `Demo(200) + Demo(300)` resulted in a `500`, since you were returning `self.data`. The next `500 + Demo(100)` was unsupported by both types.

Comment: output :<__main__.Demo object at 0x02DEB580>
how can i get sum of these 3 values..?

Comment: Access the `.data` attribute of that object…!? If you want a nicer, customised output when you `print` your object, implement `__repr__` for it.

Comment: output : 600 -- print(d1.data + d2.data + d3.data)

Comment: No… `r = d1 + d2 + d3; print(r.data)`. Or `print((d1 + d2 + d3).data)` if you have to.

Comment: its not working. r = d1 + d2 + d3; print(r.data). Or print((d1 + d2 + d3).data)

Comment: Define "not working"… https://repl.it/repls/RemarkableFastRobot

Answer (score -2):

The code should be like this-

```
class Demo:
     def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data 

     def __add__(self, other):
        self.data = self.data + other.data
        return self.data

     def __get__(self):
          return self.data


d1 = Demo(200)
d2 = Demo(300)
d3 = Demo(100)

print(d1.__get__()+d2.__get__()+d3.__get__())
```

Or you can simply do

```
print(d1.data+d2.data+d3.data)
```